# C# - How to dynamically select and load partial XML stream on TreeView's NodeMouseClick event?

Tags: c#, xml, treeview

In my project, server sends a large (>= 50MB) xml stream to client, and client displays the XML through a TreeView control.

The XMLDocument.LoadXml() method takes too long time to load the large XML stream, so I wanna dynamically load the XML content while clicking a TreeView node.

For example, if the treeview is like following:

```
- Root
 - Folder1
  - File1
  - File2
 + Folder2
 + Folder3
```

When I click Folder2 node, I expect that the XML content only corresponding to Folder2 is loaded and displayed on the ListView control on the right panel.
Any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use an XPathDocument (forward read-only) to find the folder name.  You can use an xpath expression:

```
var folder = doc.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/root/folder2");
var text = folder.ReadSubTree().ReadInnerXml();
```